# enum binding exception handling in Spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, enums, exception

I have a `enum` like as:

```
public enum Age {
    THREE("3"),
    FIVE("5");

    private final String value;

    Age(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
    return value;
    }
}
```

and a **User** `class` like:

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    String name;

    Age age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(@NotNull String name, Age age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Age getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Age age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and a `RestController` like:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseEntity<User> exceptionHandling(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception,
                                              HandlerMethod handlerMethod, WebRequest webRequest) {
    logger.error("error:" + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    EnumValidationException ex = (EnumValidationException) exception.getMostSpecificCause();
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(""); // I want set user's input
    user.setAge(Age.FIVE);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}

@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<User> exceptionHandling2(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
    logger.error("error:" + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(""); // I want set user's input
    user.setAge(Age.FIVE);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}

@PostMapping("/user2")
public String setUser2(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    return "ok";
}
```

I sed a `JSON` like:

```
{
    "name":"Name",
    "age":"11"
}
```

now how I handle its `HttpMessageNotReadableException` exceptions that return `Name` in `name` field in `response`?

should I change `enum` to `static final String`?

can I write customized `Annotaion`? how handle its `getValue()`?

**Note**: I use `Hibernate`.

Comment: Is there a mistake between Age and Gender? 11 isn't a valid value for "Age"

Comment: @Aubin :D tanQ, I edit it. Yes, 11 isn't valid and I want to handle this exception.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want to print the value of `Age`, not the 
name: in that case, you can try overriding `toString()` in `Age`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return value;
}
```

If you want to use getValue(), you should read the documentation of Spring Boot and especially its underlying JSON API:

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Comment: ThanQ @NoDataFound. This is a good idea, I override `toString()` method in `enum` and change `enum`'s to `String` in `dto`'s then use `BindingResult` in `controller` and handle exceptions manually.